# Probability the ball will be any of these colors?

Tags: probability

4 Kids are being given away tennis colored balls to play with.

Assume there are 81 blue balls, 44 red balls, 24 green balls, and 5 yellow balls

James received 4 blue balls. He only wants blue balls

Mike received 5 red balls.He only wants red balls

Stephen received 10 green balls.He only wants green balls

Amos received 3 yellow balls.He only wants yellow balls

what is the probability that the next ball(s) will go to either James, Mike, Stephen or Amos

Answer (score 1):

We are left with 133 balls: 77 blue balls , 40 red balls, 14 green balls and 2 yellow balls.

You pick a random ball from this group, so what's the probability of picking a blue, a red, a green or a yellow? I think that,from this point, it should be very straightforward to find the answer.

Comment: for blue balls the P is 4/77 or is it 77/133?

Comment: Ah ok, it makes sense now.. thanks

Comment: What if the amount of balls is unlimited. The P for any of them would be P(inf) = 0 correct?

Comment: If the number of balls of one certain color is finite , and the the total number of balls is infinite , then the probability is 0. If instead you know that you have the same amount of balls for each color , then you can figure out the probability by taking the limit